# Strtotime not correct on when calculating relative time between user login time and now

Tags: php

User login time is saved in Database(Mysql).I need the relative time betwwen login and now.

I used strtotime , but not getting correct .

First time when  login  gives strtotime as  '1322787648' , then
calculate strtotime now      '1322831782'  , then again I login in
this time it get             '1322788641'  .

Here Second login strtotime value is lesser than  strtotime('NOW') which IS calculated before second login.

I think calculating strtotime in afternoon get error but forenoon it works great.

```
    foreach ($chapterArray as $dat) {

        //$dat['date_time'] coming date from Database

        $time = strtotime($dat['date_time']);
        $now = strtotime('now');

        if (floor(($now - $time) / 86400) != 0) {
            $time = floor(($now - $time) / 86400) . ' days ago';
        }
        elseif (floor(($now - $time) / 3600) != 0) {
            $time = floor(($now - $time) / 3600) . ' hours ago';
        }

        elseif (floor(($now - $time) / 60) != 0) {
            $time = floor(($now - $time) / 60) . ' minutes ago';
        }
        else {
            $time = 'a few seconds ago';
        }
    }
```

Comment: `strtotime()` does what you tell it to - please show us what you've told it to do (i.e. show us some code)

Comment: Could you provide a script that isolates the problem? I'm suspecting time zone problems.

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you supplied. Check your database to see what actual login times were stored. I suspect the problem lies either in the code that stores the login time or the code that retrieves it.

Answer (score 0):

When doing these sort of calculations I find it best to use the mysql database to give you both times instead of mixing mysql and php times.

e.g.

```
SELECT `date_time`, NOW() as current_time FROM table
```

Then you can change your code to this:

```
$time = strtotime($dat['date_time']);
$now = strtotime($dat['current_time']);
```

This eliminates any problems with timezones, time formats (e.g. 24hr/12hr) and such, especially when the web server and the database server are seperate.

Comment: Can you make above query in cake php

Comment: I'm afraid I've never developed in cake php before.  Taking a quick look at it, I'd say you should be able to add 'NOW()' as a field.  Otherwise you'll need to use the query function - http://book.cakephp.org/view/1027/query